# Xamarin.Forms ListView scrolling slow and jerky

Tags: c#, android, listview, xamarin.forms

I have a ListView with 1 million records.

I can preload the ListView from a flat file or database (about 8 secs).

Or, load 1 million empty records into the ListView (about 1 sec), and then populate the values on the fly when ItemAppearing().

I choose the latter and it works well for Xamarin Forms 3.3.

As soon as I upgrade past 3.3 however, the scrolling becomes slow and jerky. I've tried multiple versions of upgrades over the past year and all have the same problem, meaning I'm stuck on 3.3 and am missing out on any of the benefits of later versions.

Anyone know why this might be occurring and how I might fix it. Or can anyone suggest a better design I could try.

(My listview items are actually also crashing with an object disposed error occasionally when the app is brought back into memory after being unloaded, but if I was able to upgrade, I suspect this problem might go away.)

Comment: "1 million records" - that's the problem.  Is a user on a mobile device actually going to look at even 1% of those records?  You need to think of a strategy to display some subset of **useful** information, or at least consider a lazy load.

Comment: Yeah, this is the classic "*my user is going to want to look at a million records*" problem... You are completely wrong! You need to rethink your problem

Comment: Thanks for your replies guys but neither are really helpful. If you read my post carefully I'm already doing a lazy load. It's also a dictionary application so there is no getting away from having at least 1 million dummy elements in the listview if the ScrollView is going to be accurate. The problem I'm facing is it was working perfectly fine in an older version of Xamarin Forms and now it's not.

Comment: It's really hard for us to tell you why your old codes does not work fine in new version of Xamarin Forms without seeing any codes or relevant information. Did you follow the guides in the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/) when implementing the listview?

Answer (score 2):

1 million records is a lot of records. You should go for pagination. For smooth scrolling of listview you should set **CachingStrategy="RecycleElement"**